# Including path diagram in Sweave

Tags: sweave, r

I use the following code to do sem analysis and draw path diagram with `sem R` package.

```
library(sem)

R.DHP <- readMoments(diag=FALSE, names=c('ROccAsp', 'REdAsp', 'FOccAsp', 
                'FEdAsp', 'RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES', 'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))
    .6247                                                              
    .3269  .3669                                                        
    .4216  .3275  .6404                                      
    .2137  .2742  .1124  .0839                                
    .4105  .4043  .2903  .2598  .1839                          
    .3240  .4047  .3054  .2786  .0489  .2220                    
    .2930  .2407  .4105  .3607  .0186  .1861  .2707              
    .2995  .2863  .5191  .5007  .0782  .3355  .2302  .2950        
    .0760  .0702  .2784  .1988  .1147  .1021  .0931 -.0438  .2087  

model.dhp <- specifyModel()
    RParAsp  -> RGenAsp, gam11,  NA
    RIQ      -> RGenAsp, gam12,  NA
    RSES     -> RGenAsp, gam13,  NA
    FSES     -> RGenAsp, gam14,  NA
    RSES     -> FGenAsp, gam23,  NA
    FSES     -> FGenAsp, gam24,  NA
    FIQ      -> FGenAsp, gam25,  NA
    FParAsp  -> FGenAsp, gam26,  NA
    FGenAsp  -> RGenAsp, beta12, NA
    RGenAsp  -> FGenAsp, beta21, NA
    RGenAsp  -> ROccAsp,  NA,       1
    RGenAsp  -> REdAsp,  lam21,  NA
    FGenAsp  -> FOccAsp,  NA,       1
    FGenAsp  -> FEdAsp,  lam42,  NA
    RGenAsp <-> RGenAsp, ps11,   NA
    FGenAsp <-> FGenAsp, ps22,   NA
    RGenAsp <-> FGenAsp, ps12,   NA
    ROccAsp <-> ROccAsp, theta1, NA
    REdAsp  <-> REdAsp,  theta2, NA
    FOccAsp <-> FOccAsp, theta3, NA
    FEdAsp  <-> FEdAsp,  theta4, NA



sem.dhp <- sem(model.dhp, R.DHP, 329,
    fixed.x=c('RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES', 'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))



pathDiagram(sem.dhp, file="Path", min.rank=c("RIQ", "RSES", "RParAsp", "FParAsp", "FSES, FIQ"), 
            max.rank=c("ROccAsp", "REdAsp", "FEdAsp", "FOccAsp"), same.rank=c("RGenAsp", "FGenAsp"),
            ignore.double=TRUE, edge.labels="values", size=c(8, 8), node.font=c("Helvetica", 10), 
            edge.font=c("Helvetica", 10), rank.direction="LR", digits=3,  stdCoef=TRUE,
            output.type=c("graphics", "dot"), graphics.fmt="pdf")
```

This code produces the following path diagram:

[image: Path Diagram]

with this message:

```
Running  dot -Tpdf -o Path.pdf  Path.dot
```

When I try to include the code to draw path diagram in `.Rnw` file, this extra message cause problem. I wonder how to overcome this problem so that I can use the code to create path diagram in `Sweave`. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: One solution from @chl is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8594423/707145)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
<<echo=TRUE>>=
library(sem)
R.DHP <- readMoments("sem.cov", diag=FALSE, 
                     names=c('ROccAsp', 'REdAsp', 'FOccAsp', 
                       'FEdAsp', 'RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES',  
                       'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))
model.dhp <- specifyModel(file="sem.mod")
sem.dhp <- sem(model.dhp, R.DHP, 329,
               fixed.x=c('RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES', 'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))            
capture.output(pathDiagram(sem.dhp, min.rank='RIQ, RSES, RParAsp, FParAsp, FSES, FIQ', 
            max.rank='ROccAsp, REdAsp, FEdAsp, FOccAsp'), file="sem.dot")
@
<<echo=FALSE>>=
system("dot -Tpdf -o fig1.pdf  sem.dot")
@

And here is the path diagram.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{fig1}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add the compile command? Because it doesn't work for me. I get the following error: `! LaTeX Error: File `fig1' not found.`.